# How to make ball turn blue when hit, red when missed? (Pong)

Tags: javascript

In a pong game coded using HTML and JS, how would I make the ball turn blue when it hits the paddle, and red when it misses?

```js
 // Draw Circle
 Main.Context.beginPath();       // start the circle

 // When ball crosses the paddle width, 
 // check to see if paddle intersects path
 if ( (Main.CX-Main.CRAD == 25) && (Main.XINC == -1) ) {

  // if ball hits paddle, change increment (both X & Y)
  if ( (Main.CY>Main.MY) && (Main.CY<(Main.MY+50)) ){

   Main.XINC = Main.XINC * (-1);
   Main.YINC = Main.YINC * (-1);

   Main.HITS = Main.HITS + 1;

  } else Main.MISSES = Main.MISSES + 1;

 }
 
 // If we hit a wall in x coordinate, then change x direction
 if ( (Main.CX < 0+Main.CRAD) || (Main.CX > 600-Main.CRAD)) 
  Main.XINC = Main.XINC * (-1);
 Main.CX = Main.CX + (Main.XINC); 
  
 // If we hit a wall in y coordinate, then change y direction
 if ( (Main.CY < 0+Main.CRAD) || (Main.CY > 600-Main.CRAD)) 
  Main.YINC = Main.YINC * (-1);
 Main.CY = Main.CY + Main.YINC; 

 Main.Context.arc(Main.CX, Main.CY, Main.CRAD, 0, 2 * Math.PI);   // draw the circle
 Main.Context.stroke();        // fill the circle
```

Answer (score 0):

In your conditional statement that changes the direction of the ball, you would change the color. You would do so by changing the fill color. It would make more sense to do it before you change the ball direction.

```
Main.Context.fillStyle="blue";
Main.context.fill();
```

You would do the same if the ball missed but replace blue with red.